# How can i setup "work folder" feature using Samba as server?

Tags: windows, samba, windows-server-2012-r2

After giving a look on my Windows 10's "All Tasks" menu i found a interesting feature: "Work Folders", [according to Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows-server/storage/work-folders/work-folders-overview) "a role service for file servers running Windows Server that provides a consistent way for users to access their work files from their PCs and devices".

Officially it requires a Windows server to make-up this feature, but i suppose this uses SMB as backend, so is there a way to mirror this feature using Samba as server? Currently i have a Raspberry Pi 3B with Raspbian and Samba installed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that’s not correct. Work folders uses the HTTP protocol not samba. As a result you need the HTTP web service that runs on Internet information server in order to accomplish using the work folder clients. Consider, off-line folders which which uses SMB.